# How to get list of values which are selected in radio button after click on submit in Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, angularjs-ng-repeat

Here is the HTML, this file is partial where global controller is defined in home page:message object contains data which is loaded from first page .

```
<ng-repeat data in message>
<input type="radio"  ng-model="accountValue"  value="{{data}}" name="select" />

{{data.Type}}
{{data.Number}}
```

Continue

JS:

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl',['$scope',function ($scope) {
    $scope.selectAccount = function(id) {
        alert(id);
    }
}]);
```

I am getting id as undefined . Please help.  thanks

Comment: <ng-repeat data in message>
<input type="radio"  ng-model="accountValue"  value="{{data}}" name="select" />

 {{data.Type}}
 {{data.Number}}

<button type="button" ng-click="selectAccount(accountValue)" class="bttn-text">Continue</button>

JS:

myApp.controller('myCtrl',['$scope',function ($scope) {
 
 
  $scope.selectAccount = function(id) {
         alert(id);
         
       
}]);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as per the comments what you exactly need is to share the data between two controllers (i.e Global and myCtrl ) on onclick of continue button. There are various ways in which you can do the same.

Build the service which maintain your shared object and the controllers just handle with the reference.Please note in this case it will work untill you will not refresh your page manually as per the ideal circumstances. If your data is not more heavy and you require to maintain it across all pages than in this case you can store it in localstorage.

```
Here is the demo http://plnkr.co/edit/rrFTmtnYjYNjyE8twUif
```

You can do the same things by using service & $scope.$watch method. I prefer you do not use $watch for this.Instead of assigning and watching entire service you should just needs to use setter/getter to access and share data.

```
Here is the demo http://plnkr.co/edit/N2qIMRyDj2SX2BdBleU4
```

Yep you can also use the $parent  property of the scope using ng-model. There are certainly several ways in which you can do the same things: Let's say your HTML is like below

```
<div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
   <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl"></div>
</div>
```

Then you can access your parent scope  like this

```
function ParentCtrl($scope) {
$scope.cities = ["NY", "Amsterdam", "Barcelona"];
}
function ChildCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.parentcities = $scope.$parent.cities;
}
```

Actually since you defined cities in the parent controller your child controller will inherit all scope variables. So theoritically you don't have to call $parent. The above example can also be written as follows:

```
function ParentCtrl($scope) {
$scope.cities = ["NY","Amsterdam","Barcelona"];
}
function ChildCtrl($scope) {
$scope.parentCities = $scope.cities;
}
```

The [Angular Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) are using this approach.

Comment: Thanks harsh for quick reply . I wanna pass those 2 dynamic values from list of objects to controller onclick of continue button . Could you help me on that ..

Comment: Edited the answer based on your comments.Let me know if you still do have any questions.

Comment: Thanks Harsh . I have solved it other way Using ng-model="$parent.data"

Comment: np. Any time.I have edited the answer further with $parent approach,too. Could you please up-vote ans  also if you feel it's helpful. Thank you :)