# Can I make ng-model data available across multiple divs that are hidden and shown at runtime?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem with some data I want to use as part of a signup form in angular.js. I have the form split out into multiple "steps" - such as company account information, then admin user information, and finally, payment information. This is common in many web applications, so I know it has to be possible.

I have three divs which house each section of the form, as follows :

```
<div class="lc-block" id="l-register1" data-ng-class="{ 'toggled': lctrl.register1 === 1 }" data-ng-if="lctrl.register1 === 1">

<div class="lc-block" id="l-register2" data-ng-class="{ 'toggled': lctrl.register2 === 1 }" data-ng-if="lctrl.register2 === 1">

<div class="lc-block" id="l-register3" data-ng-class="{ 'toggled': lctrl.register3 === 1 }" data-ng-if="lctrl.register3 === 1">
```

As you can tell here, these three sections are hidden and shown, based on some ui interaction which changes the valus of variables to make a given "step" appear.

So here is my main issue : I want data from a model in "l-register1" to still be available when I am on the third step, for example, if I have the following input field inside "l-register1"...

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="client" placeholder="Company name">
```

... and I hit "next" - I would like to still be able to retrieve that data during steps 2, and 3 - as I will obviously need it after all the data is in place, to send it off to my API (which I already have working)

Any help with this would be awesome, I have been banging my head against a wall all day, trying to get this working!

Comment: When you are changing steps are you actually going to another page or just hiding and showing these divs?

Comment: I am using the code above to hide and show divs.

Answer (score 0):

Just put all your ng-model and associated variables in one controller and you can hide and show your different div's based on  conditional variables. Thus, as you put all your variable references within one controller it will automatically preservers the data associated with it. Also if you would like to use different controllers for the different page than you can also achieve the same. In that case you need to make service and share the data between two controllers. Just build the service which maintain your shared object and the controllers will handle with the reference. I have explained more with detail information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32200820/how-to-get-list-of-values-which-are-selected-in-radio-button-after-click-on-subm/32203300#32203300). In totality that's what whole angular is all about single page application.

Comment: they are all within one controller - but it doesn't work :(

Comment: Could you please be specific what exactly you mean by doesn't work ? Any specific problem ? A plunker would be added advantage to help you quickly.

Comment: I will try and sort it out myself, I hate plunkr, you basically have to rewrite your application over there to get an example working, and I would rather get this fixed that spend a day on plunkr.