# how do i display data on next page when form was submitted?

Tags: angularjs, forms, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I am new to angularjs,i made a sample app on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/D5S2c6rgycWFfsyfhN9J?p=preview) i am trying to display data that user enter after submit on other page.When user click on submit button the user data page should be displayed and all data given by user is displayed there.
here is my sample app index.html:

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>

        <!-- define angular app -->
         <html ng-app="scotchApp">

         <head>
          <!-- SCROLLS -->
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css" />

        <!-- SPELLS -->
         <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
         <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
         <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.8/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
         <script src="script.js"></script>
          <script src="homeDirective.js"></script>
       </head>

          <!-- define angular controller -->
        <body ng-controller="mainController">

          <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
           <div class="container">
           <div class="navbar-header">
           <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Angular Routing Example</a>
         </div>

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#home"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
           <li><a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> About</a></li>
           <li><a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
       </div>
        </nav>

        <div id="main">

        <!-- angular templating -->
        <!-- this is where content will be injected -->
         <div ui-view></div>

         </div>

         <footer class="text-center">
               View the tutorial on <a href="http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating">Scotch.io</a>
         </footer>

         </body>

       </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy approach to this would be to store the submitted form data inside a service using a variable that is updated upon submit.

Then upon route change, the router can resolve the form data by making a request to that service for it before loading the next view, resulting in it being available for the next controller.

Hope that helps you out!

Comment: could you please add this in to my plunker? i want on click submit user page will open and all data show there

Comment: I'm afraid I'm unable to do this for you. This is something you will need to implement yourself. However, using a service will be the correct approach for what you're aiming to do.

Comment: If you would like to see the concept and the various ways in which you can do it than in one of the another question oft the same context i have explained you can [check](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32200820/how-to-get-list-of-values-which-are-selected-in-radio-button-after-click-on-subm/32203300#32203300) it with plunker.